# Policy: deleting "identify" questions after 30 days

Tags: discussion, identify

I was just [informed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/a-movie-with-an-orphan-falling-overboard) that

> ... ID questions without upvoted\approved\any answers are usually deleted after 28 days.

Now, assuming that it's a good question, the user has done their research, and there is enough information for someone who has seen the movie to answer the question (or provide extra detail), I want to know what the harm is in leaving the question around?

If there are few upvotes and no answers, the question should sink pretty quickly and not bother anyone.

There is however, a clear benefit: it can still be found on Google. Given a billion internet users and few decades, there may well be a few people with the same question, and possibly build towards an answer. This is the value that unanswered SE question provide: a single page that a handful of people with the same question across the planet and across time can find through Google.

So why remove the questions? Is it just some idea that the database should be kept "clean" or is there a real benefit to not having them lying around?

Comment: I haven't figured out all of the "rules"... there is a list but it doesn't seem to be correct... but, essentially, this isn't always true.... if you look at our top-voted questions, one of them is an [ID question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38772/identify-tongue-in-cheek-movie-with-exploding-heart-punch-technique) that's been around for more than 30 days but the question is upvoted... so perhaps your previous question wasn't voted up?

Comment: Same [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37213/embarrassed-student-goes-on-a-killing-spree-and-makes-a-kill-list-with-heros-na).

Comment: [This meta question](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1671/extend-the-policy-for-deleting-inactive-identification-questions/1672#1672) is the full "decision"... and the most recent one, I believe...

Comment: @Catija, thanks. I thought it was a much more strict policy. Glad to see it's not. I guess I misinterpreted the discussions I skimmed. I suppose just deleting the badly written ones is not a problem.

Comment: I totally forgot the 'inactivity' part when I commented on your question, sorry!

Comment: @Peter even the badly written can be resurrected on demand by us (mods) if they can be improved, feel free to raise this kind of request.

Comment: Related question explaining the entire policy: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1417/49.